# Broken gnome-keyring file and google-chrome hangs

Tags: gnome, password, google-chrome, keyrings, gnome-keyring

After few weeks of uptime yesterday I rebooted my laptop.
After that, I discovered that there is no password in gnome-keyring. gnome-keyring segfault and didn't work. I restored ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring from backup from last week, but it didn't help. gnome-keyring still segfault.

In desperation, I restored version from few months ago. It helps - gnome-keyring start working correct, but there aren't my recent passwords.

It's not a very big problem, most of passwords are up-to-date, but there is another issue. When I start google-chrome - it starts, then gnome-keyring-daemon start working with 100% CPU usage, and after few minutes - gnome-keyring slows, but google-chrome hangs - didn't respond to mouse and keybord. killall chrome helps ;)

I have read passwords from my last backup of login.keyring by simple python script and I can use it in another browser - but it's not a useful solution. Does anybody have any idea how to:

- recover recent passwords from .keyring file which hangs gnome-keyring-daemon
- fix connection between gnome-keyring and Google Chrome?

Comment: Maybe it's related to this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1174162

Answer (score -2):

Ugly fix: remove gnome-keyring execute privilege.

```
chmod -x /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon
```

After this, gnome-keyring-daemon will not make any Chrome issue anymore, but it will not save any system password (google chrome password will be saved and you can used saved one too).